# Segmentation fault with aapt

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services, aapt

Trying to build and Android project using Maven, we are not able to compile it with google play services apklib with it.

I've tried to remove all the languages from the apklib, just keeping the default one, and it seems to be able to execute aapt with no problems.

Does anybody run into this problem? I've tried to do what Jake Wharton says in this website: https://github.com/JakeWharton/gms-mvn-install , but the Segmentation fault still happening.

Ideas?

Thank you for your time.

aapt: warning: string 'error_generic_text_toast' has no default translation in /Users/fjfernandez/Development/android-messenger/app/target/unpack/apklibs/com.google.android.gms_google-play-services_apklib_5/res; found: ca_ES cs de en eu_ES fr gl_ES it nl pt pt_PT sk
Segmentation fault: 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem we had in code was in style. You cannot use @+id to make reference to any view ( I guess you should not reference any kind of view in your styles, but anyway).

**No @+id** in your styles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already solved this problem, but I find out if I don't define in Manifest package like "package=some.app.package" it gave me the same error like you had.

Answer (score 0):

I had a menu file with unresolved @string reference. I copied the aapt command from the Eclipse Console tab and ran it in a standalone terminal window. I figured out the offending file from the aapt log.

```
(new resource id main from /home/paller/workspaces/android_dev/xxxxxx/res/menu/main.xml)
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It does not look nice that aapt just crashes if it does not like something in its input files.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that when strings.xml contains %blabla%, aapt segfaults. I have created an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68667